# UserPasswordEncoderInterface Autowiring Not Working Symfony 4.4

Tags: php, symfony4

I have a super basic API endpoint with a fresh install of symfony 4.4 and I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot autowire argument $passwordEncoder of
> "App\Controller\AuthenticationController::authenticateAction()": it
> references interface
> "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface"
> but no such service exists.

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Encoder\JWTEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;

/**
 * Class AuthenticationController
 *
 * @package App\Controller
 * @Route("/api/authentication")
 */
class AuthenticationController extends AbstractFOSRestController {

    /**
     * @Rest\Get("/authenticate")
     *
     * @param Request                      $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @param JWTEncoderInterface          $JWTEncoder
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticateAction (Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, JWTEncoderInterface $JWTEncoder) {
        exit;
    }
}
```

If I remove `UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder` I get a successful nothing (expected for now). My `User` Entity is nothing special, and extends `UserInterface` correctly.

services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

Using Symfony 4.4 and php 7.2.20

Almost certain this is some sort of configuration issue, but I'm not following what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man am I smart, it was a config issue!

My `security.yaml` file was in main `/config` directory and not in the `/config/packages` directory. Ok maybe I'm not that smart...

Not sure how it got there. I think some out-dated package couldn't find it in the `config/packages` directory.

There goes 48 hours of my life...

Comment: Did you manually created the `security.yaml` file? O.o

Comment: Nope, it was auto-generated when I ran `composer require symfony/security-bundle`. Like I said, it must have been some out-dated package that didn't like where it was or something. Not sure why I would have moved it otherwise. :shrug: